# Cоздать страницу с фоном любого цвета, при клике в любую область которой осуществляется закрашивание фигуры определенного размера

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

***Вот собственно сам код:***

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var first = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
        $('#first').click(function (circle) {

        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Нужно как-то сделать так, что был определенный цвет задан body, при щелчке будет появляться квадрат заданного размера, но при этом не использовать canvas для рисования.

***Вот так должно выглядеть:***
[image]

Comment: откуда у вас вы коде взялось `#first`?

Comment: создал, разве так нельзя создавать элементы?

Comment: Какие то определенные фигуры?

Comment: эм, а вы читали документацию `jquery`?

Comment: я только начали изучать jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот мой вариант решения:

```js
$('#first').click(function(event) {
  let element = '<div class="element" style="left: ' + (event.pageX - 25) + 'px; top: ' + (event.pageY - 25) + 'px;"</div>';
  $('#first').append(element);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#first {
  background: #FF7F50;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.element {
  background: #01FFFF;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за данное решение!

Answer (score 1):

Мне понравился принятый ответ... хотел немного поиграться, по инерции случайно создал редактор))) Это конечно издевательство над DOM, но ради прикола прокатит)

*Можно рисовать и линии, зажатой кнопкой мышки.

[JsFiddle (HTML - paint)](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/m0hz9L2r/)

```js
(function(){
let color = "#f36700";
let size = 30;
let shape = "border-radius:50%;";
let pressed = 0;
/* если pressed = 1; значит мышка зажата, а если 0 - нет */
$('#first').on('mousedown', function(){
  pressed = 1;
});
$('#first').on('mouseup', function(){
  pressed = 0;
});

let ele;
/* Рисуем при клике */
$('#first').on('click', function (e) {
  ele = '<div style="position: absolute; left:' + 
  (e.pageX - size/2) + 'px; top:' + 
  (e.pageY - size/2) + 'px; width:' + 
  size + 'px; height:' + size +'px; background-color:'+
  color+';' + shape + '"></div>'
  $('#first').append(ele);  
});

/* Также рисуем, если нажать и таскать мышку */
$('#first').on('mousemove', function (e) {
  if(pressed == 0) {return}
  ele = '<div style="position: absolute; left:' + 
  (e.pageX - size/2) + 'px; top:' + 
  (e.pageY - size/2) + 'px; width:' + 
  size + 'px; height:' + size +'px; background-color:'+
  color+';' + shape + '"></div>'
  $('#first').append(ele);  
});

/* Меняем краску (document, чтобы динамически добавленные цвета тоже работали)*/
$(document).on('click', '.color', function(){
  $('.color').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  color = this.style.backgroundColor;
});
/* Меняем форму */
$('.shape').on('click', function(){
  $('.shape').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  shape = this.dataset.shape;
});
/* Меняем размер */
$('#size').on('change', function(){
  size = this.value;
  $('#sizenum').val(size);
});
/* Меняем размер (вручную введенные числа в input) */
$('#sizenum').on('input', function(){
  size = (this.value > 1) ? this.value : 2;
  $('#sizenum').val(size);
});
/* Выбранный цвет из input type="color" станет текущим */
$('#custom').on('change', function(){
  $('.color').removeClass('active');
  color = this.value;
});
/* Добавляем выбранный цвет в палитру */
$('#add').on('click', function(){
  $('#colors').append('<div class="color" style="background-color:'+ $('#custom').val() +'"></div>');
});
/* Удаляем цвет из палитры */
$('#delete').on('click', function(){
  $('.color:last-child').remove();
});
/* Стираем всё нарисованное */
$('#clear').on('click', function(){
  $('#first').empty();
});

})();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#first {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  user-select: none;
}

.element {
  background: orange;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px; border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

#block {
  position: fixed; top: 0;
  background-color: #22282b;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
#colors {display: flex;}
.color {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shape {
  border: 2px solid black; 
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 4px; cursor: pointer;
}
.active { color: black; border: 2px solid red; text-align: center;}
.color.active:before {content: '✓'; position: absolute; color: white; top: -3px; left: 2px;}
.text {margin: 0 4px; color: #eee;}
#size {width: 100px; text-align: center; height: 14px;}
#sizenum {width: 40px; text-align: center;}
#custom {
  width: 20px; height: 18px; 
  border: 1px solid #236; outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0; margin: 0; cursor: pointer;
}
#clear { margin-left: 4px; cursor: pointer; }

#add, #delete { 
  width: 20px; height: 18px; margin: 0 0 0 4px; text-align: center; 
  background-color: #ddd; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid #236;
  user-select: none; transition: 1s; border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Tahoma'; font-size: 14px;
}
#add:active, #delete:active { color: red; border-color: red; background-color: white; transition: 0s;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="first"></div>

<div id="block">
  <span class="text">Custom:</span>
  <input type="color" id="custom" value="#ffa500">
  <div id="add">+</div>
  <div id="delete" style="margin-right: 4px;">X</div>
  <div id="colors">
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #c00;"></div>
    <div class="color active" style="background-color: #f36700;"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #eb0;"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #070;"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #0af;"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #045acf;"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #ac3390;"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #ffe2aa;"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #000;"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #800;"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="text">Shape:</span>
  <div class="shape" data-shape=""></div>
  <div class="shape active" data-shape="border-radius: 50%;" style="border-radius: 50%;"></div>
  <span class="text">Size:</span>
  <input id="size" value="30" min="2" type="range">
  <input id="sizenum" value="30" min="2" type="number" step="5">
  <button id="clear">Clear</button>
</div>
```